# Hyphenation for words with underscore

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

Can I tell LaTeX that it may hyphen words that contain an underscore `_` always before the underscore?

I have a lot of code examples in text, like `is_error_condition_enum` and I would like to tell LaTeX it may hyphen this as:

```
Lorem ipsum is_error_-
condition_enum lorem.
```

always.

If that is not possible globally, how do I make an entry for some underscore-words like:

```
\hyphenation{is_-error_-condition_-enum}
```

because that entry is rejected, obviously.

In sourcecode I write words like these as `\gpmono{is\gpus{}error\gpus{}condition\gpus{}enum}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\gpus}{\_\discretionary{-}{}{}}
```

If `\gpus` is used in other places where hyphenation is not wanted, you can modify its definition only in the argument of `\gpmono`:

```
\newcommand{\gpmono}[1]{\begingroup
   \renewcommand{\gpus}{\_\discretionary{-}{}{}}%
   \ttfamily#1\endgroup}
```

Of course, without knowing your original definitions of `\gpmono` and `\gpus`, I tried to guess.

Comment: Ok, I looked up the definition of `\gpus` (comes from the style I use) and inserted `\renewcommand{\gpus}{\symbol{"5F}\discretionary{-}{}{}}` into my document. It works ok now. But a question: Does this now "inject" `\discretionary` at all my usings of `\gpus`? Is that necessary? Would it not be enough to define/declare it at one specific place once? I have no idea how `\discretionary` works (obviously).

Comment: Yes, it will use `\discretionary{-}{}{}` in all places where `\gpus` is found. In alignments it will have no effects, unless the cell is a "paragraph cell", where you of course *want* again the hyphenation.

Answer (score 11):

The [`underscore`](http://ctan.org/pkg/underscore) package provides a way to do this automatically: It modifies the defintion of the `\_` command in order to allow hyphenation after the underscore. Furthermore, it allows you to simply write `_` instead of `\_` in text mode to produce an underscore. Everything you have to do is loading the package with

```
\usepackage{underscore}
```

Comment: Did you actually try this with the `\hypenation{}` (TeX!-)command? Because for me it's not working at all. Getting the same error: `Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. ...`

Answer (score 3):

The package [hyphenat](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) enables hyphenation in words that contain underscores.

For example, the following TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
Lorem\_ipsum\_dolor\_sit\_amet,\_consetetur\_sadipscing\_elitr,\_sed\_diam\_nonumy\_eirmod\_tempor\_invidunt\_ut\_labore\_et\_dolore\_magna\_aliquyam\_erat,\_sed\_diam\_voluptua.\_At\_vero\_eos\_et\_accusam\_et\_justo\_duo\_dolores\_et\_ea\_rebum.\_Stet\_clita\_kasd\_gubergren,\_no\_sea\_takimata\_sanctus\_est\_Lorem\_ipsum\_dolor\_sit\_amet.\_Lorem\_ipsum\_dolor\_sit\_amet,\_consetetur\_sadipscing\_elitr,\_sed\_diam\_nonumy\_eirmod\_tempor\_invidunt\_ut\_labore\_et\_dolore\_magna\_aliquyam\_erat,\_sed\_diam\_voluptua.\_At\_vero\_eos\_et\_accusam\_et\_justo\_duo\_dolores\_et\_ea\_rebum.\_Stet\_clita\_kasd\_gubergren,\_no\_sea\_takimata\_sanctus\_est\_Lorem\_ipsum\_dolor\_sit\_amet.
\end{document}
```

produces this output:
[image]

As you can see, it does both hyphenation after underscores and within words.