# Hyphenate when using underscore as a letter

Tags: macros, punctuation, hyphenation

In many place in my current text I have to insert something like `Name_of_model` for instance. I found the last suggestion in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20892/412) very helpful. However, I am facing a problem when it come to hyphenation of the argument of the macro `\escapeus`. How can I improve `\escapeus` so it will enable hyphenation of the argument. In particular, if hyphenation is needed, it should put it right after an underscore, for example: `Name_of_-model`.

Inspired by [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28184/412), I tried to modify the definition given by @egreg [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20892/412) as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\escapeus}[1]{%
  \begingroup\@activeus\scantokens{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_\discretionary{-}{}{}}}
```

All my attempts (which included moving the `_` around) failed.

**How can I improve the code above, so it will enable hyphenation of the argument of `\escapeus`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\let~\_\discretionary{-}{}{}
```

defines `_` to be `\_` then inserts the discretionary *at the point of definition* You intended

```
\def~{\_\discretionary{-}{}{}}
```

That fixes your original definition, an alternative mechanism, which doesn't work in the original OT1 encoding, is just to make _ a normal character then you will get some automatic hyphenation (more if you used special patterns) and can specify hyphenation points in `_` words using `\hyphenation`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\textwidth3cm

\catcode`\_=12
\lccode`\_`\_

\hyphenation{four_-fifty-five_-six one_-two_-three}

\begin{document}


one two thee four one_two_three four_fiftyfive_six
one two thee four one_two_three four_fiftyfive_six


\end{document}
```