# Hyphenation for words with underscore locally

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

I am trying to hyphenate long keywords like given in the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\parbox{1pt}{TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION}
\\\\

%\begin{figure}[here]
%\centerline{\includegraphics*[width=0.8\paperwidth]{/pictures/regular_testname.png}}
%\centerline{\includegraphics*[width=0.8\paperwidth]{/pictures/escaped\_testname.png}}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28208/34240) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132658/34240) and more without success. If I uncomment the figures in the example, the `underscore`-package produced problems because the underscore in the filenames isn't interpreted properly anymore. Without using this package, the pictures can be inserted, but I don't get my strings hyphenated.

Do you have an idea how to hyphenate properly and just locally, like e.g. in that kind: `TESTSTRING\myUnderTESTSTRING\myUnderHYPHENATION`?

And how can I control that no hyphen is written while hyphenating the string? This would be even preferable.

As a side-question: In my example, why isn't the first part of the string being hyphenated?

Comment: First word of a paragraph is not hyphenated, which explains the intiial "TESTSTRING"

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thx for this. Can I control it? My final goal is to use the hyphenation for keywords in several `parbox` in a table/tabular environment.

Comment: Using `\hspace{0pt}TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION` will allow the first word to be hyphenated.

Comment: Without the `underscore` package, hyphenation can be achieved with `\hspace{0pt}TESTSTRING\_\allowbreak\hspace{0pt}TESTSTRING\_\allowbreak\hspace{0pt}HYPHENATION`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would help, without using the `underscore` package, which you would seem to prefer (not using it).  It activates the hyphenability with `\newuson` and restores the original definition of `\_` with `\newusoff`.  Through this on/off mechanism, you can control the scope of the modifications.

Also, the "hyphenation" of the underscore is without the dash, which also seemed to be desired, if I understood the question properly.

In any case, to get the first word of a paragraph to hyphenate, a `\hspace{0pt}` is required to start the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{underscore}
\textwidth0pt
\let\svus\_
\newcommand\newuson{\def\_{\svus\allowbreak\hspace{0pt}}}
\newcommand\newusoff{\let\_\svus}
\begin{document}
TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION

\newuson
\hspace{0pt}TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION

\newusoff
TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Could you please explain what the command is doing? Why do I need `\textwidth0pt` or `\let\svus\_`? And what is it doing?

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace `\textwidth0pt` is merely to test the method by making the document line of zero width, which essentially tries to hyphenate everything in sight.  It is like your `\parbox{1pt}{}` artifice.  Thus, it can go.  The `\let\svus\_` needs to stay.  It makes a copy of the originally defined `\_`, in order to avoid self-reference when redefining `\_` subsequently.  Also, it provides the copy that gets reinstated by `\newusoff`.

Comment: A more compact version:
`\newcommand\myunderscoredword{\let\svus\_\def\_{\svus\allowbreak\hspace{0pt}}UNDER\_SCORE\_STRING \let\_\svus}`

Answer (score 4):

If you are keen to keep your long strings with underscore as the argument to a macro, it's easy:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\Name[1]{{%
  \let\_\hyphenationunderscore#1%
}}
\newcommand{\hyphenationunderscore}{%
  \textunderscore\nobreak\hspace{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\parbox{1pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}%
  \Name{TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also redefine `\_` globally:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\_}{%
  \textunderscore\nobreak\hspace{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\parbox{1pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}%
  TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION
}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can make `_` active:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\hyphenationunderscore}{%
  \textunderscore\nobreak\hspace{0pt}%
}
\catcode`_=\active
\protected\def_{\ifmmode\sb\else\hyphenationunderscore\fi}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\parbox{1pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}%
  TESTSTRING_TESTSTRING_HYPHENATION
}

\end{document}
```

Note that without `\hspace{0pt}` you get no hyphenation in the `\parbox`, because TeX doesn't hyphenate a word that's not preceded by glue.

If you want to break also after the underscore, change `\nobreak` into `\linebreak[0]` throughout. For instance, the second solution becomes

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\_}{%
  \textunderscore\linebreak[0]\hspace{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

  TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION

\parbox{1pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}%
  TESTSTRING\_TESTSTRING\_HYPHENATION
}

\end{document}
```

The output here also shows what happens with T1.

[image]

Comment: Your 1) idea isn't working in my table/tabular environment. What do you mean with your 3) by making `_` active?

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace When a character is made active, it behaves like a macro (and should be given a definition). As for the first solution not to be working, something more should be seen: are you sure you add some space (even zero) before the string?

Comment: Yes I add `\hspace{0pt}` in front. Also in your example the string isn't hyphenated at the location of the underscore. The code of @Steven B. Segletes is doing so. Nevertheless, thx for the effort, I am using the `\newuson` now.

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace If you want to split also after the underscore, it's just a matter of changing `\nobreak` into `\linebreak[0]`.