# Extra space in \lstinline

Tags: listings, inline

When using the `\lstinline` macro from listings, like

```
\lstinline|subl|
```

some extra whitespace is added to the intended text. It is especially painful at the end of the line: it behaves as if it were a new paragraph, and adds some unwanted indentation. How can I get rid off this? See the example below: the comma immediately following `\lstinline` goes to the beginning of the next line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines,postbreak=\kern-1ex}
\textwidth=4cm
\parindent=0cm
\begin{document}
normal text normal text \lstinline{reg1}, \lstinline{reg2}, normal text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Will these `\lstinline`s always fit on one line or can the be expected to linebreak in the middle of the `\lstinline`?  If one line, then `\mbox{\lstinline{reg1},}` would work.

Comment: Check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200494/21891

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes The extra whitespace remains, so this solution only prevents line break, but not continuous writing.

Comment: I understand from you reply that you need the ability to perform line breaks within the `\lstinline`.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes No, I simply want a smooth continuation, i.e. no space before the next comma, especially not to transfer  the comma to the beginning of the next line; and especially not to put the extra white space to the beginning of the next line, within a paragraph.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes I simply want to write a continuous text, like "instructions like \lstinline|add|, \lstinline|sub| and \lstinline|mul|" and the unwanted space in \lstinline makes the output ugly, either by separating the inline text and the comma following it, or even starting an unwanted indentation in the next , starting with space and comma at the beginning.

Comment: If your `\lstinline` argument always consists of a single word (without spaces), then the `\mbox{\lstinline{reg1},}` approach I mentioned above should work fine.  The issue is if you have a multi-word argument that you desire to break across lines, that is a more difficult problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `breaklines,postbreak=\kern-1ex` options here when you say you don't need to break inline listings across lines? Removing those options fixes the issue